# Add UITextfield to UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uialertview

I need to add two `UItextfield` into `UIAlertView`. With iOS 5, I can use `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` to add it. But I need to add 2 textfields. I don't want to use `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`, because I need them are in difference section.

Can I use alert `addSubview` method. Apple allows this ?

Any advice!

Comment: *Apple allows this?* Only God and Apple can tell.. I used addSubview method in pre iOS 5 era, and it passed the validation. But I don't think anyone here can correctly answer the question.

Comment: Not a specific programming question which can be answered authoritively.

Comment: Please check my answer and approve it if you got what you was looking for else let me know if any more clarification needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by add subview to your alertview:

```
UIAlertView *aAlert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"yourTitle" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Change", nil];
UITextField *aText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)];

[aAlert addSubview:aText];

UITextField *aText2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 80.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[txtNewPassword setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[aAlert addSubview:aText2];
[aAlert show];
```

**If you wonder will apple approve it?**

No one can answer this question except Apple itself but yes it will work and I have few of my app live with this solution. So I can say apple won't object it but they can change their mind anytime ;)

hope this helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this for UItextfield into UIAlertView. you can do using this

[ddalertprompt](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ddalertprompt)
[shakingalertview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/shakingalertview)

Comment: Probably because 1) You are not answering OP's question, OP does know how to add UITextField in UIAlertView, his question is different  2) This is a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). If the link goes down for some reason, your answer is useless. Links are fine, as long as answer is complete without the link.